# How to save backbuffer to file in DirectX 10?

Tags: screenshot, directx-10

I want to render a video frame-by-frame using DirectX 10. The frames would be processed later by some other tool like mencoder or ffmpeg.

I had no problems doing so in DX9 using `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile`.

Now, in DX10 I've found `D3DX10SaveTextureToFile`, but had no luck using it to save my backbuffer.

I use the following code:

```
ID3D10Resource *backbufferRes;
_defaultRenderTargetView->GetResource(&backbufferRes);

D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
texDesc.BindFlags = 0;
texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D10_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
texDesc.Format = backbufferSurfDesc.Format;
texDesc.Height = backbufferSurfDesc.Height;
texDesc.Width = backbufferSurfDesc.Width;
texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
texDesc.SampleDesc = backbufferSurfDesc.SampleDesc;
texDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_STAGING;

ID3D10Texture2D *texture;
HRESULT hr;
V( _device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, 0, &texture) );
_device->CopyResource(texture, backbufferRes);

V( D3DX10SaveTextureToFile(texture, D3DX10_IFF_DDS, filename) );
texture->Release();
```

This creates a .dds image that can not be opened by any sort of DDS view/editor I know of.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the credit goes to sepul of gamedev.net.

Now, the problems:

- `texDesc.CPUAccessFlags` should be 0
- `texDesc.Format` should be `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM`
- `texDesc.SampleDesc.Count` should be 1
- `texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality` should be 0
- `texDesc.Usage` should be `D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT`

This way `D3DX10SaveTextureToFile` will save to BMP even to PNG.

The complete code is:

```
HRESULT hr;
ID3D10Resource *backbufferRes;
_defaultRenderTargetView->GetResource(&backbufferRes);

D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
texDesc.BindFlags = 0;
texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
texDesc.Width = 640;  // must be same as backbuffer
texDesc.Height = 480; // must be same as backbuffer
texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
texDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
texDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;

ID3D10Texture2D *texture;
V( _device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, 0, &texture) );
_device->CopyResource(texture, backbufferRes);

V( D3DX10SaveTextureToFile(texture, D3DX10_IFF_PNG, L"test.png") );
texture->Release();
backbufferRes->Release();
```