# How to render a texture in DirectX 11 and transfer the texture to regular memory?

Tags: directx, rendering, directx-11, render-to-texture

I wanna render an image to a texture taking advantage of DirectX acceleration.
But instead of showing that image on the screen, I wanna get this image back to the regular memory as a bitmap to do anything with the result. How do I transfer some texture to the regular memory?
I am using DirectX 11.

Comment: You can find the same problem, and the solution, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120108/how-to-save-backbuffer-to-file-in-directx-10). You only need to use DirectX 11 version instead of 10.

Comment: almost there... In fact I want to have ACCESS to the pixels. D3DX10SaveTextureToFile() does it in background of course. But I wanna know how to do it by myself. I think it's something related to Map/Unmap of resources(DX10/DX11), but I couldn't find anything that really works! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a seperate "staging" texture which has cpu read access. Than copy your rendertarget texture to this staging texture  with CopySubresource() or CopyResource() an perform Map() to this staging texture.

--> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476259(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh, I saw that's the solution in the comments above...
I used this several times and it works. Whats your problem with Map/Unmap?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it in DirectX 12? It seems that many memory related things have changed there :(